# How to remove subtext in shipping checkout summary

Tags: checkout, shipping, checkout-summary

I need to remove subtext of shipping in checkout summary
here tried as below location
[image]

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-web/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js
```

here I returning blank but still `()` is appearing. how to remove this

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ],
    function ($, Component, quote) {
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/shipping'
            },
            quoteIsVirtual: quote.isVirtual(),
            totals: quote.getTotals(),
            getShippingMethodTitle: function() {
                if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                    return '';
                }
                var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();
                return shippingMethod ? '' : '';  //HERE Returning Blank***
            },
            isCalculated: function() {
                return this.totals() && this.isFullMode() && null != quote.shippingMethod();
            },
            getValue: function() {
                if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                    return this.notCalculatedMessage;
                }
                var price =  this.totals().shipping_amount;
                return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

where am I doing wrong? Can I get help? Thank you in advance

Comment: clear cache and do static-content:deploy then it will come , but override core files to your local folder and do changes

Comment: You need to remove it from web html file.

Comment: Which Magento version you are using?

Comment: Thank you  @Dhaduk Mitesh for replaying. am using  Magento 2.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found my answer by
Overriding below file

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-web/Magento_Checkout/web/template/cart/totals/shipping.html

```
<th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row" data-bind="text: title + ' (' + getShippingMethodTitle() + ')'"></th>
```

Replace this With

```
<th class="mark" colspan="1" scope="row">SHIPPING COST</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `shipping.html` in your theme.

```
<!-- ko if: quoteIsVirtual == 0 -->
    <tr class="totals shipping excl">
        <th class="mark" scope="row">
            <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: title"></span>
            <!-- <span class="value" data-bind="text: getShippingMethodTitle()"></span> -->
        </th>
        <td class="amount">
            <!-- ko if: isCalculated() -->
            <span class="price"
                  data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: isCalculated() -->
            <span class="not-calculated"
                  data-bind="text: getValue(), attr: {'data-th': title}"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </td>
    </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And comment span tag and then check it.

Comment: Thank you @Dhaduk Mitesh for replaying. am overriden file `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-web/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/shipping.html`. did static-content:deploy. But its still its same

Comment: Have you comment value span tag?

Comment: yes I commented.

Comment: Check custom `shipping.html` is call or not.

Comment: I Commented in vendor and overridden file both. according to path I think it is calling. `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-web/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/shipping.html`

Comment: Then put log in all `shipping.html` and see where it come from. You need to now debug it.

Comment: `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-web/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/shipping.html` for this path am not getting logs , I did upgrade,deploy, is this path is correct??

Comment: Yes, now add log in core file also. and check that it is call in core or custom.

Comment: Also flush cache. Also clear cache of your browser.

Comment: I changed in core file as in overridden file . added log, opening in incognito , did upgrade, deploy , compile, cache flushed, but nothing changed in Checkout summery and no logs in console.

Comment: Now disable cache from browser and check it.

Comment: And also check that your site is in developer mode.

Comment: my site is in `Production` mode, i disabled site cache but no use. only `()` coming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102937/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-praveen-negimani).